# How to read Zwoptex XML files in Xcode?

Tags: xml, xcode, zwoptex

When Zwoptex files are saved in the uncompressed zssxml format, many of the characters are unreadable when the file source is viewed in Xcode.

Is there some kind of setting or encoding that needs to be set so that it can be read in Xcode like an ordinary xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that these files cannot be read directly in Xcode as they are in binary. The format zssxml is now obsolete and is not expected to be used.